# JavaFx: is it possible to check if an item has a specific style class?

Tags: java, css, javafx

Im making buttons that need to switch between two colors every time they are pressed. I wanted to do that by comparing the style class to see if it matches either the "green" or "red" css class. Like so.

```
if(clickedBtn.getStyleClass() == "green") {
            clickedBtn.getStyleClass().add("red");
        } else {
        clickedBtn.getStyleClass().add("green");
        }
```

This doesn't work as it doesn't recognize "green" as anything. Is there a simpler way of doing this? I just need a graphic display with selectable seats. Thanks

Comment: Not to talk about comparing strings now, but `getStyleClass()` returns a list not a string. Use `getStyleClass().contains("red")`.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the old when adding the new, otherwise both styles will apply and the one later in the style sheet will have precedence.

Comment: Now, for your "selectable seats" use a `ToggleButton` instead.

Comment: Also consider using a `PseudoClass`.

Comment: PseudoClass is the way to go. It is semantically more correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.getStyleClass()` retruns a `ObservableList` containing the style classes. This will never be the same object as a string literal, so the `==` check always yields `false`. The proper way of checking, if a node has a style class would be invoking the `contains` method of the list:

```
if (clickedBtn.getStyleClass().contains("green")) {
```

Since you probably want red and green to be mutual exclusive. you should also remove the style classes:

```
if(clickedBtn.getStyleClass().remove("green")) {
    clickedBtn.getStyleClass().add("red");
} else {
    clickedBtn.getStyleClass().remove("red");
    clickedBtn.getStyleClass().add("green");
}
```

Using pseudo classes would probably be a bit more convenient however:

```
private final static PseudoClass GREEN = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("green");
private final static PseudoClass RED = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("red");

...

boolean isGreen = clickedBtn.getPseudoClassStates().contains(GREEN);
clickedBtn.pseudoClassStateChanged(GREEN, !isGreen);
clickedBtn.pseudoClassStateChanged(RED, isGreen);
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer!